# when to convert to load store architecture

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I am converting peudo code instructions to  load store architecture to see the number of interleavings. I know some processes do not have to be converted to  load store architecture.

This is my list so far of general rules to follow.

**Atomic-actions**

- flag = boolean
- while(condition)
- if(condition)
- volatile variable ?

**Non-Atomic Actions**

- n = n *2
- n = k+1
- n = n+1
- Long variables
- Double variables

Anyone know any other ones that I am missing? Please correct me if I am wrong thinking the above is true.

**Reference:** *"Principles of Concurrent and Distributed Programming, Second Edition by M. Ben-Ari"*

[image]

Comment: What about long variables? There is [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html)

Comment: In the book i referenced above it says that the long and double are atomic. 
Atomic long implements Serializable. I think that is why it is considered atomic too

Comment: No, "atomic" and "serializable" are completely unrelated.

Comment: Nice readable book. It is good you mention `volatile`: also a boolean might get stale (its updated value not seen in another thread) if it is not volatile. And then there is that one volatile field suffices, to update all fields in the current JVM specification. And yes only _volatile_ longs and doubles are atomic.